# widget.getProductId is not a function

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I have upgraded the Magento from 2.3 to 2.4.2, Now on the product page getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: widget.getProductId is not a function
```

**File path:** `Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi/js/swatch-renderer.js`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging for a while, I found the issue:

Edit the file:
vendor/magento/module-inventory-swatches-frontend-ui/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

go to line 22:
configurableVariationQty(productVariationsSku[widget.getProductId()], salesChannel, salesChannelCode); //line 22

replace "widget.getProductId()" with "widget.getProduct()"

flush the CSS and re-built the static files